# Check taken location on Tic Tac Toe board Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, input, user-input, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make a small function that checks whether a spot is taken on a Tic Tac Toe board or not. I have created an array of zeroes called tttArray where when each spot is filled, its location is changed to 1. So I first take the input from the player from the below function.

```
function [pXInputRow, pXInputCol] = pickXspot(playerInput)
%This function is to take inputs from Player X
pXInputRow = 0;
pXInputCol = 0;
%Set text for Row/Col Prompt
prompt = {'Row (1,2, or 3)', '(Col (1, 2, or 3)'};
name = 'Player X Turn';
%Show prompt to input values
playerInput = inputdlg(prompt, name);
pXInputRow = str2num(playerInput{2});
pXInputCol = str2num(playerInput{1});
tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol) = 1;
end
```

And then use the below function to see if the spot is taken.

```
function  [spotTaken] = checktaken(tttArray)
%Function used to check if spot is taken
%Setup Error Messages
errorMessage = 'This spot is taken, please choose another spot';
errorMessageTitle = 'Spot Taken';
if tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol) || tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) == 1
    msgbox(errorMessage, errorMessageTitle)
    spotTaken = 1;
end
end
```

However, I keep getting the following error after I run and put a row/col in the prompt dialog box. Any Suggestions?

```
Not enough input arguments.
Error in checktaken (line 8)
if tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol) || tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) == 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980638/tic-tac-toe-with-a-win-and-taken-check-matlab Solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems.

You supplied the **tttArray** as an input parameter to your **checkTaken** function as a call argument:

```
function  [spotTaken] = checktaken(tttArray)
```

but you do not appear to have supplied the row and column parameters  pXInputRow, pXInputCol or pOInputRow, pOInputCol as arguments.

So those parameters are undefined when you call

```
if tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol) || tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) == 1
```

You need to supply those coordinates as arguments to your checkTaken function.

You could do the brute force method

```
function  [spotTaken] = checktaken(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol)
```

or you could do something more elegant like put the coordinates in an array.

Another problem is if you want to check if either of the array elements is equal to 1, your if statement syntax is  not correct.

in effect you have

if a || b == 1

but that is probably not what you want. Se the Matlab documentation on [operator precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html)

Instead you probably want

if (a == 1) || (b == 1)

so you if statement should be

```
if (tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol)  ==1) || (tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) == 1)
```

Comment: For some reason, Matlab still says the function requires more inputs.... I'm not sure what else I need to put in now? However, I did fix the syntax error, good catch, thanks.