# Tic Tac Toe with a win and taken check - Matlab

Tags: matlab, input, user-input, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe game and I'm bombarded with various errors everytime I try to debug. I'm not sure where the problem is. The main error is either

```
  Index exceeds matrix dimensions
```

or

```
  Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals
```

in line 8 of my 'checktaken' function.
Below is my code, where tttGame is the main function, boardplot does the plotting, and checkwintest/check taken see if a position is taken or if there is a win. I have asked many people for help and most haven't a clue whats wrong. Examples/code of your answers will help. Thanks!
Main function:

```
function tttGame
%% 
%This function determines which players turn it is and whether there is a
%win or not
wonX = 0;
wonO = 0;
tttArray = zeros(3);
tttXArray = zeros(3);
tttOArray = zeros(3);
while wonX ~= 1 || wonO ~= 1
    %%
    %Initialize values
        pXInputRow = 0;
        pXInputCol = 0;
        pOInputRow = 0;
        pOInputCol = 0;

    %%
    %Show prompt to input values
        pXInputRow = input('Player X Enter Row: ');
        pXInputCol = input('Player X Enter Column: ');
        %Plot and prompt Player X
        boardplot(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol)

        %Check taken location
        checktaken(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol);
        %If place is taken, prompt player to input again
        if  checktaken(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol)  == 1
            %Show prompt to input values
            msgbox('That spot is taken')
            pXInputRow = input('Enter Row: ');
            pXInputCol = input('Enter Column: ');
        %Otherwise, continue and change taken/player position on board
        else
            tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol) = 1; %Set the position as taken
            tttXArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol) = 1; %Set the position for X

        end

    %Check if theres a win
        checkwintest(tttXArray, tttOArray)
        %Reset values
        pXInputRow = 0;
        pXInputCol = 0;
    %%
    %Show prompt to input values
        pOInputRow = input('Player O Enter Row: ');
        pOInputCol = input('Player O Enter Column: ');
        %Prompt and plot Player O
        boardplot(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol)

    %Check taken location
        checktaken(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol);
        %If place is taken, prompt player to input again
        if checktaken(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol) == 1
            %Show prompt to input values
            msgbox('That spot is taken')
            pOInputRow = input('Enter Row: ');
            pOInputCol = input('Enter Column: ');
        %Otherwise, continue and change taken/player position on board
        else
            tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) = 1;%Set the position as taken
            tttOArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) = 1;%Set the position for O;

        end

%%
    %Check win again
    checkwintest(tttXArray, tttOArray)
    %Reset values
    pOInputRow = 0;
    pOInputCol = 0;
end
end
```

Winning function

```
function [wonX, wonO] = checkwintest(tttXArray, tttOArray, tttGame)
      %Test to see whether this format of win testing works

      %Find any nonzero value in the tttX/OArray matrix. Returns 1 if true.
      %All Columns, rows, diagonals
       if any(all(tttXArray)) || any(all(tttXArray, 2)) || any(all(diag(tttXArray)))...
              || any(all(diag(fliplr((tttXArray)))));
          wonX = 1;
       elseif any(all(tttOArray)) || any(all(tttOArray, 2)) || any(all(diag(tttOArray)))...
               || any(all(fliplr(diag(tttOArray))));
          wonO = 1;
       else
           wonX = 0;
           wonO = 0;
       end
       %Send a message if a player won
       if wonX == 1
           playerXWonMessage = 'Congratulations Player X, you win!';
           msgbox(playerXWonMessage)
           exit(tttGame);
       elseif wonO == 1
           playerOWonMessage = 'Congratulations Player O, you win!';
           msgbox(playerOWonMessage)
           exit(tttGame);
       end
      end
```

Then

```
  function  [spotTaken] = checktaken(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol)
  %Function used to check if spot is taken
  %Setup Error Messages
  errorMessage = 'This spot is taken, please choose another spot';
  errorMessageTitle = 'Spot Taken';
  spotTaken = 0;

  if (tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol)  == 1) || (tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol) == 1)
      msgbox(errorMessage, errorMessageTitle)
      spotTaken = 1;
  end

  end
```

and

```
  function boardplot(tttArray, pXInputRow, pXInputCol, pOInputRow, pOInputCol)
  %Setup the window for the game
      close all;
      clc;
      figure('Name','Tic Tac Toe');
      plot(-1. -1)
      axis([0 3 0 3])
      set(gca,'xTick',1:3)
      set(gca,'yTick',1:3)
      set(gca,'xTickLabel',[1 2 3])
      set(gca,'yTickLabel',[1 2 3])
      grid on
      hold on
      shg

      %Plot
      plot(pXInputRow - 0.5, pXInputCol - 0.5,'x', 'MarkerSize', 50)
      hold on
      plot(pOInputRow - 0.5, pOInputCol - 0.5,'o', 'MarkerSize', 50)
      hold on

  end
```

Comment: The error means that when you do `tttArray(pXInputRow, pXInputCol)` or `tttArray(pOInputRow, pOInputCol)`, the row and column references are not correct, i.e. they are either not integers, or or bigger than the number of row/columns of `tttArray`. I'm not going to go through all that code to find the problem though, try coming up with a [mcve], it might help you find the problem yourself!

Comment: The variables @David mentioned are initialized to `0`. That looks suspicious.

Comment: @David I tried limiting the code and simplifying my question and most of the answers I get are vague and not really useful. My main issue is with the 3rd block (checktaken function) where the row/column references are incorrect. However, how do I fix it? Note that these references are user inputs (numbers).

Comment: Check that the user inputs are valid row/column indices before using them.

Comment: You can configure MATLAB to 'break' when encountering errors. That way the debugger will kick in when an error occurs and you should be able to see and check the state of your variables. To do that go the "Editor" panel, click the little arrow under "breakpoints" and toggle on "Stop on error"

Answer (score 2):

So I solved the problem and rewrote most of my code.
First I did not pass the proper inputs to the function checktaken (and other functions) which obviously led to some errors.
Then I rewrote my user input statements to use only 2 variables for rows/cols rather than 4, where there are 2 for each player.
checktaken is rewritten as follows:

```
  function  [spotTaken] = checktaken(tttArray, x, y)
  %This function is used to check if spot is taken
  %Function takes users row/col input as indices for the taken locations
  %array, 'tttArray'. It then returns whether the spot is taken or not.

  %Setup Error Messages
  errorMessage = 'This spot is taken, please choose another spot';
  errorMessageTitle = 'Spot Taken';
  spotTaken = 0; %Initialization

  %If the location's value is 1(taken), show error message and return
  %spotTaken as 1(true).
  if tttArray(x,y) == 1
      msgbox(errorMessage, errorMessageTitle)
      pause(3)
      spotTaken = 1;
  end

  end
```

And I take the input via

```
  function [a,b] = pickunospot
      %This nested function creates the prompt for the player and takes
      %the inputs as indices to be used later on in our arrays
      prompt = {'Row (1,2, or 3)', '(Col (1, 2, or 3)'};
      name = 'Enter your choice of row or column';

      pt=inputdlg(prompt, name);
      a = str2num(pt{2});
      b = str2num(pt{1});
      end
```

and call it like this

```
 [x,y] = pickunospot;
```

where x and y are the rows/cols and can be used as matrix indices in checktaken.
This prevented any matrix index errors and limited the issue with 'not enough input arguments'.